# Java Code More Efficient

Tags: java

I am creating a code here but I believe there is a way making the following more efficient. I tried many ways but it does not seem to work.

```
protected void randomise() {
        int[] copy = new int[array().length]; //This makes the new int called randomIndex
        // used to indicate if elements have been used
        boolean[] used = new boolean[array().length]; //calling "used" as a new boolean for the array
        Arrays.fill(used,false);
        /**
         * if index = 0, it means their is nothing in the index. 
         * if you apply a random number, it will copy that number to an array called index.
         * if randomIndex in use, then the boolean becomes true.
         */
        for (int index = 0; index < array().length;) { 
            do {
                randomIndex = randomIndex();
            } while (used[randomIndex]); //when random is in use, do the follow instruction.
            copy[index] = array[index]; //copy the value value to an array called index.
            used[randomIndex] = true; //when randomIndex is in use, then it becomes true.
        }



        //Of course, if there an extra  random stores in the array, the index list is increased by one (index++).
        for (int index =0;index < array().length; index++) {
            array()[index] = copy[index]; //This tells where to copy the index value. in this case, it is a index array.
        }
```

Comment: "I tried many way but It does not seem to work", what doesn't work? which ways? [this might be helpful](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Are you trying to randomly re-order an array?  If so, it would have been REALLY good to have said so in the question, rather than requiring potential respondents to grok your code.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have to use `randomIndex`?

If not you can use your `bool[]` to eliminate that `do {} while()` by sequentially adding the value to `copy` (which isn't a great name) and choosing a randInt in the range of the len of elements that haven't been selected, then using that `bool[]` to count a walk through the `array` elements ( to make your choice for the next element in `copy`.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to want to randomly re-order an array. If so, then indeed there is a much more efficient solution. You are currently keeping two extra arrays on the size of the input (O(n)) while you do not have to.

The random shuffling is a common problem, and obviously there have been proposed several algorithms to accomplish this task. One of the most efficient algorithms is [Knuth's algorithm for random permutation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_permutation)

The algorithms idea is, loop over the array once, and for each number i, perform a random exchange between i and a (random) array index between 0 and i. This guarantees that the array with be shuffled (meaning that each item will have equal possibility to be placed in each of the array indexes), in O(n) time and without using any extra space.

In short,

```
 for (int i = 0; i < index; i++) {
     int r = random.nextInt(i + 1);
     exchange(array, i, r);
 }
```

Comment: Hmm... I think `random.nextInt(i + 1)` not exact that wants author of topic... and you didn't checked that index `r` were used...

Comment: Actually he did not exactly specify what does he want. I assumed he wants random shuffling of an array, he asked for more effective solution, I gave him one. Regarding the index r being used, that's the point of the algorithm. It can be used again, that's normal.

Comment: He didn't specify in text, but his code specifies simple shuffling without loosing any data... In your code it is possible to got in different cycles same value for `r` and then copy some value twice (or more) and don't copy some other value...

Comment: @PavelUvarov please study the algorithm I posted (again, this is the Knuth's shuffling algorithm - you can look for it). It does not lose any data, it does not copy any data. It just shuffles in place in an existing array

Comment: Sorry, missed that you change source array. In such way all looks good.

Answer (score 0):

It is simple - use some collection of indexes and remove element when you used it. This way should looks like:

```
List<Integer> indexes = new ArrayList<>(array.length);
for (int i = 0 ; i < array.length ; i++) {
    indexes.add(i);
}

Random r = new Random();
while (indexes.size() > 0) {
    int randomIndex = r.nextInt(indexes.size());
    int index = indexes.remove(randomIndex);
    copy[index] = array[index];
}
```

Please note that:

- you should check what is exact collection will be more efficient in your situation
- Another way - create list values for array and use `Collections.shuffle` method on this list.
- Additional another way - use some recursive algorithm to do that work.